# Text transformed incorrectly after JSoup transform

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I use JSoup to parse HTML. I have a text string of:

```
   &ap
```

After parsed using:

```
Jsoup.parseBodyFragment("&ap");
```

It is transformed to a wired character: `≈`

The character is actually from an URL:

```
 http://mycompany.com?param=1&app=100
```

Notice that the `&ap` part of URL is always replaced with the wired character hence the URL becomes:

```
http://mycompany.com?param=1≈p=100
```

I think this might be something to do with HTML encoding.

Can someone let me know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Could you provide more information how to reproduce that?
I tried it with this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    Document doc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment("<a href=\"http://mycompany.com?param=1&app=100\" />\n<p>http://mycompany.com?param=1&app=100</p>");

    System.out.println(doc.toString());
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(doc.getElementsByAttribute("href"));
}
```

It prints:

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <a href="http://mycompany.com?param=1&amp;app=100"></a> 
  <p>http://mycompany.com?param=1&amp;app=100</p>
 </body>
</html>

<a href="http://mycompany.com?param=1&amp;app=100"></a>
```

And there the `&` got translated into `&amp`.